# Python - sleep interval, account for various options (int or randrange)

Tags: python

I am trying to learn python by contributing to some projects.
Currently there is a --sleep_interval that takes int x which does as you would expect.

I would like to expand the functionality of sleep_interval to accept something like this:

--sleep_interval=100-200

If the input is in the format of "int-int", we should use a random interval within that range.

Current state -

```
sleep_interval = self.params.get('sleep_interval')
        if sleep_interval:
            self.to_screen('[download] Sleeping %s seconds...' % sleep_interval)
            time.sleep(sleep_interval)
```

I was guessing at perhaps doing something like this:

```
sleep_interval = random.randrange(int(self.params.get('sleep_interval').split('-')[0]), int(self.params.get('sleep_interval').split('-')[1]))
```

So, I guess this could be done with if/else logic.
However, the input "100-200" would be a string, right?

What is the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Canaryyellow's answer is correct but - as far as user input is provided - be sure to provide a useful error message when input is invalid. Hence, my code would end up with something like:

```
sleep_interval = self.params.get('sleep_interval')
if '-' in sleep_interval:
    try:
        start, stop = sleep_interval.split('-')
        sleep_interval = random.randrange(int(start), int(stop))
    except ValueError:
        raise ValueError("Invalid range 'a-b' provided: expected 'a' to be integer smaller integer 'b'")
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd just do this:

```
if '-' in sleep_interval:
  start,stop = sleep_interval.split('-')
  sleep_interval = random.randrange(int(start),int(stop))
```